# How to return positive and negative numbers when reading a file

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a code that reads a file line by line and return only the following lines, as an example:

> int int0 = (-953);
>       int int1 = (-411);
>       int int2 = 5471;
>       int int3 = 823;

After that I would like to return only the numbers both positive and negative. To do that, I wrote the following:

```
String str = line.replaceAll("\\D+","");
System.out.println(str);
```

The result of running this code is:

> 0953
>       1411
>       25471
>       3823

The output that I seek is:

> -953
>       -411
>       5471
>       823

How can I do that?

Comment: does the number can be float ?

Comment: @Thomas Look at the variable naming 0, 1, 2, 3, then look at the start of each output number ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to capture the *last sequence of digits* in a line (optionally preceded by a minus sign), you can do it with a capturing group, something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?(-?\\d+)\\D*$");
String line = "int int0 = (-953);";
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Result:

```
-953
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

Due to your situation where each number will be after a `=` and what I want to do here is to remove everything else just as you once tried in this part (after `=`).

```
s = s.split("=")[1].replaceAll("[^-0-9]", "");
```

Local test your input with:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String[] ss = {"int int0 = (-953);", "int int1 = (-411);", "int int2 = 5471;", "int int3 = 823;"};
    for (String s : ss) {
        s = s.split("=")[1].replaceAll("[^-0-9]", "");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
-953
-411
5471
823
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this: **([-+]?)\d+**

- **[-+]?** will match the- or + and ? means if exist or not exist
- **\d+** any digit 0-9 and + means 1 or more times